# Permalink in anchor tag in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to set permalink in anchor tag in Wordpress, but I'm getting the following result:

http://localhost/mysite/the_permalink();

Here is my code:

```
 $result .= '<footer><a href="the_permalink();'.$link_value.'" >'.get_the_title().'</a></footer>';
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Use get_permalink() instead the_permalink

```
  $result .= '<footer><a href='.get_permalink().$link_value.' >'.get_the_title().'</a></footer>';
```

`the_permalink` directly outputs the permalink of the current post to the frontend.

`get_permalink` returns it as a variable, but does not echo it out.

Answer (score 0):

As `the_permalink()` function directly echoes URL, your code need just a slight change. It will be like following:

```
    $result .= '<footer><a href="'; the_permalink();
    $result .= $link_value.'" >'.get_the_title().'</a></footer>';
```